# TYPO3 website multilanguage configuration

Tags: configuration, typo3, multilingual

I want to configure a multi language TYPO3 website. I tried to put this code to Page TSConfig

```js
config {
        linkVars = L
        sys_language_uid = 0
        sys_language_overlay = 1
        sys_language_mode = content_fallback
        language = sq
        locale_all = sq_AL.UTF-8
        htmlTag_setParams = lang="sq" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
        config {
                sys_language_uid = 1
                language = en
                locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
                htmlTag_setParams = lang="en" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
        }
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
        config {
                sys_language_uid = 2
                language = it
                locale_all = it_IT.UTF-8
                htmlTag_setParams = lang="it" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
        }
[global]
```

but when attaching the L parameter with sys_language_uid to the page URL, nothing happens. My template is :

```html
  #about
  ABOUT = CONTENT
  ABOUT { 
    table = tt_content
    select {
      where = colPos=1
      languageField = sys_language_uid
    }
  }
```

I Have translated the content in Page Module.
Am I using this right or not? How can I properly configure the languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code you have shown above goes to TypoScript Setup. Not in the Page TS Config in the page properties.

Use the "Template" module on the left as admin in your TYPO3 backend. When you edit the template, it has two parts for code: `Constants` and `Setup`. Use that code in setup and clear the cache.